# Backbone accessing data/event of other view

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views

I have a view1 of fuelux grid with a formatter of combo box for an additional column. I also have another view2 where there are menus.  On click of some button/dropdown in view2, I have a event captured.

In view2, how do we access view1's combo box? You probably guessed, I am very new to development.

Comment: I just went through - http://www.benknowscode.com/2013/01/managing-events-between-multiple_3253.html.   Is the option2 better? Or would Marionette is something that deals with it better?

Answer (score 0):

This is the pattern I haven been using:

in the global namespace (App)
define an event dispatcher

```
App.Dispatcher = _.clone(Backbone.Events);
```

in view2, you don't wanna access view1's combo box. I'm not sure what you wanna do here, but i'm assuming you want something to happen with the combo boxes when the button/dropdown is clicked in view2.

so, to do this, in your view2.

```
view2 = Backbone.View.extend({
  //other view stuff
  events: {
    'click button': 'onClickButton'
  },

  onClickButton: function() {
    App.Dispatcher.trigger('buttonClicked', [event params you wanna pass]);
  }
});
```

and in view1.

```
 view1 = Backbone.View.extend({
  //other view stuff

  initialize: function() {
    //other view initialize suff
    App.Dispatcher.on('buttonClicked', this.handleButtionClicked, this);
  },

   handleButtionClicked: function() {
     //do stuff to combo boxes
   }
});
```

basically, the idea is, when you click on a button in view2, view2 notifies this event thru the global App.Dispatcher. and view1 subscribes to this event on App.Dispatcher, and when it's triggered, view1 should know how to handle it.

Comment: Great! This sounds great with global event handler for inter view event communication. I should have explained before - but what I really want is - since view1 has combo box in grid, multiple combo box can be selected in view1 grid.Now view2 which is menu view has a drop down/button - which when gets clicked - need to know which all comboboxs are selected in view2. Is this something i have to create global variables and find push that in view1 combo selection and access that in view1..I really don't like the global pool mechanism..there should be some elegant way. Appreciate your help!

Comment: I see. I can't see your app so I don't really know if the design decision of putting them into two different views is correct. But in your case, I would create a model (backbone model) to maintain the status of the combobox, and pass it to both views. when any of the comboboxes in view1 has changed, update the attributes on the model, and in view2, when a button is clicked, read the attributes in the model to decide what needs to be done.

Comment: Thanks Yurui! I will try it out and keep this posted.